# How to create a checkbox with a link, without triggering checkbox checked event in Quasar q-checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pug, quasar

I am trying to create terms and conditions checkbox using q-checkbox. The label of the checkbox should be something like this, 'I have read and understood the' part should not be clickable, and the User Clarification Text part should be clickable that opens a popup when clicked, i have tried this:

```
 .row
   q-checkbox(color="primary" v-model="termsAccepted")
   div
     .text-regular.no-pointer-events.text-primary(style="text-decoration: none")
       | I have read and understood the
     .cursor-pointer.text-primary.text-regular.text-underline(@click="openConditionsDialog()" style="text-decoration: underline")
       | User Clarification Text.
```

@click event is not triggered and both texts are apart from each other, and not even near to checkbox, i also tried using q-checkbox's default slot

```
q-checkbox(v-model="val" style="cursor:auto")
  I have read and understood the
  a(@click="openPopup") User Clarification Text.
```

It works and triggers the event but when clicked, it also checks the checkbox, i don't want that, can you help me find a better solution?

Comment: Interactive elements like links can't go within other interactive elements like checkboxes

Comment: @Sean Why not? Maybe it *shouldn't* if some specification says so, but they surely can. And there are ways to make it work, so the question would be "how" or "what are the alternatives".

Answer (score 2):

This is not my decision, I spied it on the Quasar discord. Weird but works well

```
<q-checkbox ...>
  <a @click.stop="(event) => event.stopPropagation()"  href="..."> ... </a>  
</q-checkbox>
```

Comment: This can actually be written even more concise, like this: 
`<q-checkbox ...>
  <a @click.stop  href="..."> ... </a>  
</q-checkbox>`
The .stop modifier already prevents the click event from propagating further. So it has the same effect as `@click.stop="(event) => event.stopPropagation()"`